# Propositions Parser using recursion in Elm

Tags: parsing, recursion, logic, logical-operators, elm

Yesterday, I posted about an assignment I got for parsing logical propositions. After a lot of research and trying different things, I got it to work for individual propositions: going from a string to my own custom type Proposition. However, now I am at a complete roadblock - I have almost no idea how to combine these components to work for more complex propositions. I am not even sure whether they are suitable to be combined and work together. You will the code and the screenshot of my current output below, any advice / ways for approaching this would be greatly appreciated!

```
type Proposition
  = A 
  | B 
  | C
  | And Proposition Proposition
  | Or Proposition Proposition
  | Implies Proposition Proposition
  | Not Proposition
  | Equal Proposition Proposition

andParser : Parser Proposition
andParser =
  oneOf
    [ succeed A
        |. keyword "A"
    , succeed B
        |. keyword "B"
    , succeed C
        |. keyword "C"
    , succeed And
        |. symbol "&"
        |. spaces
        |. symbol "("
        |. spaces
        |= lazy (\_ -> andParser)
        |. spaces
        |. symbol ","
        |. spaces
        |= lazy (\_ -> andParser)
        |. spaces
        |. symbol ")"
    ]

orParser : Parser Proposition
orParser =
  oneOf
    [ succeed A
        |. keyword "A"
    , succeed B
        |. keyword "B"
    , succeed C
        |. keyword "C"
    , succeed Or
        |. symbol "|"
        |. spaces
        |. symbol "("
        |. spaces
        |= lazy (\_ -> orParser)
        |. spaces
        |. symbol ","
        |. spaces
        |= lazy (\_ -> orParser)
        |. spaces
        |. symbol ")"
    ]

implParser : Parser Proposition
implParser =
  oneOf
    [ succeed A
        |. keyword "A"
    , succeed B
        |. keyword "B"
    , succeed C
        |. keyword "C"
    , succeed Implies
        |. symbol ">"
        |. spaces
        |. symbol "("
        |. spaces
        |= lazy (\_ -> implParser)
        |. spaces
        |. symbol ","
        |. spaces
        |= lazy (\_ -> implParser)
        |. spaces
        |. symbol ")"
    ]

equalParser : Parser Proposition
equalParser =
  oneOf
    [ succeed A
        |. keyword "A"
    , succeed B
        |. keyword "B"
    , succeed C
        |. keyword "C"
    , succeed Equal
        |. symbol "="
        |. spaces
        |. symbol "("
        |. spaces
        |= lazy (\_ -> equalParser)
        |. spaces
        |. symbol ","
        |. spaces
        |= lazy (\_ -> equalParser)
        |. spaces
        |. symbol ")"
    ]

notParser : Parser Proposition
notParser =
  oneOf
    [ succeed A
        |. keyword "A"
    , succeed B
        |. keyword "B"
    , succeed C
        |. keyword "C"
    , succeed Not
        |. symbol "N"
        |. symbol "("
        |. spaces
        |= lazy (\_ -> notParser)
        |. spaces
        |. symbol ")"
    ]

my_results: List String
my_results =
    [     "and parser test ____& (A , B)______",
          pr <| Parser.run andParser "& (A , C)",
          "or parser test ____ | (A , B) ______",
          pr <| Parser.run orParser "| (A , B)",
          "implies parser test ____ > (A , B) ______",
          pr <| Parser.run implParser "> (A , B)",
          "equal parser test ____ = (A , B) ______",
          pr <| Parser.run equalParser "= (A , B)",
          "equal parser test ____ N ( A ) ______",
          pr <| Parser.run notParser "N(B)",
          "parsing & ( N (B) ) C",
          pr <| Parser.run andParser "& ( A, N(B) ) "
    ]
```

Code output so far:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there, but you need a parser that can parse any kind of proposition, and you need to call that recursively instead of the individual parsers. There's a couple ways you can do that. The easiest is to just put all your existing parsers in a `oneOf`:

```
propositionParser : Parser Proposition
propositionParser =
    oneOf
        [ andParser
        , orParser
        , implParser
        , equalParser
        , notParser
        ]
```

and just call that from the other parsers, e.g. from `notParser`:

```
notParser : Parser Proposition
notParser =
  oneOf
    [ succeed A
        |. keyword "A"
    , succeed B
        |. keyword "B"
    , succeed C
        |. keyword "C"
    , succeed Not
        |. symbol "N"
        |. symbol "("
        |. spaces
        |= lazy (\_ -> propositionParser)
        |. spaces
        |. symbol ")"
    ]
```

This has a lot of duplication though, as the variables are parsed for each expression, which would ale make it error-prone to add more variables. So let's simplify by moving those into `propositionParser`:

```
propositionParser : Parser Proposition
propositionParser =
    oneOf
        [ succeed A
            |. keyword "A"
        , succeed B
            |. keyword "B"
        , succeed C
            |. keyword "C"
        , andParser
        , orParser
        , implParser
        , equalParser
        , notParser
        ]
```

which will allow us to remove the `oneOf` from the individual parsers, since they're only handling one case each:

```
notParser : Parser Proposition
notParser =
    succeed Not
        |. symbol "N"
        |. symbol "("
        |. spaces
        |= lazy (\_ -> propositionParser)
        |. spaces
        |. symbol ")"
```

You should now be able to see that the structure of the parser mirrors the type it parses. We now have a `propositionParser` with a `oneOf` where each case corresponds to a case from the `Proposition` type, and with each individual case parser using `propositionParser` where the type says it needs a `Proposition`. Knowing this, you should hopefully be able to create a parser for any custom type by creating small parsers for each individual piece, and then combine them by simply mimicking the structure of the type.